# Where is the parameter in this spring bean comming from

Tags: java, lambda, spring-bean, circuit-breaker

I am new to Spring and need to use the circuit breaker pattern, so I looked at the [Spring Cloud Circuit Breaker](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-circuitbreaker/docs/current/reference/html/) project and saw this code

```
@Bean
public Customizer<Resilience4JCircuitBreakerFactory> defaultCustomizer() {
    return factory -> factory.configureDefault(id -> new Resilience4JConfigBuilder(id)
        .timeLimiterConfig(TimeLimiterConfig.custom().timeoutDuration(Duration.ofSeconds(4)).build())
        .circuitBreakerConfig(CircuitBreakerConfig.ofDefaults())
        .build());
 }
```

where is the **factory** coming from? is it injected?

The project where this code came from is here [demo](https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/spring-cloud-circuitbreaker-demo)

cheers,

es

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing injected.

The methods return a new instance of `Customizer<Resilience4JCircuitBreakerFactory>`

The code could also be written like this:

```
@Bean
public Customizer<Resilience4JCircuitBreakerFactory> defaultCustomizer() {
        return new Customizer<Resilience4JCircuitBreakerFactory>() {
            @Override
            public void customize(Resilience4JCircuitBreakerFactory factory) {
                factory.configureDefault(id -> new Resilience4JConfigBuilder(id)
                        .timeLimiterConfig(TimeLimiterConfig.custom().timeoutDuration(Duration.ofSeconds(3)).build())
                        .circuitBreakerConfig(CircuitBreakerConfig.ofDefaults())
                        .build());
            }
        };
    }
```

But because `Customizer` is a functional interface it can be written in a lambda.